# Pandas changing data types of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert all the values in certain columns into floating point dollar amounts, in the pre-existing columns they have a dollar sign before them, however, they are strings which contain the dollar amount as a whole number. All cells in these columns have values that are not (NaN).

I'm importing this from a read .csv file which is assigned to the variable props and I am looking to convert the values to floats from the following columns: Land Value, Improvement Value',Total Value, and Sale Price

my code at this point is

```
 col_list = ['Land Value', 'Improvement Value','Total Value','Sale Price']
 for item in col_list:
   props[item] = float(props[item].rstrip('$'))
```

How exactly can I convert the values in these 4 columns into floating point dollar amounts?

Answer (score 0):

This should work to deal with most cases. Remove the dollar sign with replace and then `pandas.to_numeric()` will convert it to a float. Anything that isn't a number is coerced to `np.NaN`, giving you a column with `dtype: float64`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Land Value': ['$10.31', '$17.81', np.NaN, 'NaN', None, '$ 102.13']})    

pd.to_numeric(df['Land Value'].str.replace('$', ''), errors='coerce')
#0     10.31
#1     17.81
#2       NaN
#3       NaN
#4       NaN
#5    102.13
#Name: Land Value, dtype: float64
```

Just make sure to assign it back in the end.

```
col_list = ['Land Value', 'Improvement Value', 'Total Value', 'Sale Price']
for item in col_list:
    props[item] = pd.to_numeric(props[item].str.replace('$', ''), errors='coerce')
```